# "You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure"." error through AWS codedeploy running Powershell

Tags: aws-code-deploy

Running AWS Codedeploy on multiple nodes is failed due to "You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure"." even the fact these keys are set as a part of the original snapshots.
Once I run this procedure on a single node it works fine.
Tried to put the 'Set keys' commands as a part of the PS, but no effect on this error.

Any clue?